# Using applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed with Mac Catalyst

Tags: ios, objective-c, appkit, mac-catalyst

I have a Mac Catalyst app that's essentially a one-window app, but I added multi-window support (using scenes) to allow opening a second window for one function, which a small portion of users will use. Now Apple has rejected the app because with multi-window support, the app doesn't quit when a user clicks the red button at the top of the main window. One solution is to provide a menu item to reopen it, but I think it would be more intuitive for users if the app simply quit as it did before.

I found a similar problem [on the Apple forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/124769) and am trying to implement the provided solution. Using [this tutorial](https://crunchybagel.com/disabling-the-mac-zoom-maximise-button-in-catalyst/) that provides more setup instructions, I have added a macOS bundle as a new target, embedded that into the iOS target, and added this class to the bundle:

```
#import "AppKitBridge.h"

@implementation AppKitBridge

@synthesize application;
@synthesize window;

- (id)init {
    NSLog(@"AppKitBridge init");
    self = [super init];

    self.application = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
    self.window = [[self.application windows] firstObject];
    if (self.window) {
        self.application.delegate = self;
        self.window.delegate = self;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"AppKitBridge error: window is nil");
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)test {
    NSArray *windows = NSApplication.sharedApplication.windows;
    for (NSWindow *window in windows) {
        NSLog(@"AppKitBridge window: %@", window);
    }
}

- (void)applicationDidUpdate:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"AppKitBridge applicationDidUpdate");
}

- (BOOL)applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:(NSApplication *)sender {
    NSLog(@"AppKitBridge applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed");
    return TRUE;
}

- (NSApplicationTerminateReply)applicationShouldTerminate:(NSApplication *)sender {
    NSLog(@"AppKitBridge applicationShouldTerminate");
    return TRUE;
}

@end
```

Then in viewDidLoad of the initial view controller of the iOS app, I call this method to load the bundle:

```
- (void)enableAppKit {
    NSString *pluginPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] builtInPlugInsPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"AppKit.bundle"];
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:pluginPath];
    [bundle load];
    NSObject *appKit = [[[bundle classNamed:@"AppKitBridge"] alloc] init];
    [appKit performSelector:@selector(test) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}
```

When I run the app, the console shows the `AppKitBridge init`, `AppKitBridge window` and `AppKitBridge applicationDidUpdate` lines. So it seems like the overall setup is working. But when I click the red window button, it does not show the `AppKitBridge applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed` or `AppKitBridge applicationShouldTerminate` lines, and the app does not quit.

Should this do what I'm expecting, and if so, what am I missing in the setup?

Comment: I'm trying to piece this together from several articles that show one part or another of the technique. I haven't found a complete explanation, and I've never done anything like embedding bundles before, so it's likely I am missing something.

Comment: Okay, I get it. I was only initializing the AppKitBridge class to test that the bundle was loading, and didn't realize the main app needed to initialize and retain that instance in order for it to keep working. That fixed it! If you want to formulate this as an answer, I'll accept it. (I don't need the "rock bottom basics of Objective-C," I was just unfamiliar with this AppKit bridging idea and didn't know the pieces fit together.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
NSObject *appKit = [[[bundle classNamed:@"AppKitBridge"] alloc] init];
```

Your `appKit` object is a *local variable* so your AppKitBridge instance goes out of existence one line later. You need this object to *persist* if it is to function as the app/window delegate. Assign it to an instance property of some persistent object.

Comment: Great! I can confirm that everything works as expected after making this change.